# Creating a stacked histogram

Tags: r, matplotlib, gnuplot, histogram

I have this data file:

```
A
    169
    164
    164
    102
    150
    100
    145
B
    145
    107
    115
    120
    140
```

I want to create a stacked histogram out of it. I'd like to set a range (let's say 100 to 170), set bin width (let's say 10) for X axis and that it will count how much it has in each bin (for example 140 to 149 would have 1 in A and 2 in B) and plot the count in Y axis using bars. The coloring (or hatching or whatever) would be different for the A count and B count.
I tried looking at the histogram demos of gnuplot and it does seem similar in some cases, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. Also no luck with python+matplotlib or R.
Reordering the data to something like

```
 A B
 169 145
 164 107
 164 115
 102 120
 150 140
 100
 145
```

Is not a problem if needed.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you make a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Well the closest I got to making something similar was playing with the gnuplot examples of the histograms. In there it seems that the data format is takes is already counted, that is I need to give it something like this:
    100-109 110-119 etc..
    4 2 etc...
But in that case I can do the counting myself in python (for example). I'm sort of looking for a simple solution. If you're familiar with GMT, similar to the pshistogram command, only with support for 2 or more data sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite easy to make a stacked histogram using Hadley Wickham's `ggplot2` package in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
h <- data.frame(var=sample(letters[1:2], 100, TRUE), 
                value=rnorm(100, 0, 10))

ggplot(aes(x=value, color=var), data=h) + stat_bin(binwidth=5)
```

Removing the `color=` bit would produce a simple histogram.

Comment: Also, try using `fill` instead of `colour`.